# Importing Spotify API Client Library through Maven / Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, maven, spotify

I want to use this wrapper to access the Spotify Web API using Java, via an Eclipse IDE :
https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java

However, I have zero knowledge of Maven and working with external libraries. I imported this project using "File > Import > Existing Maven Projects..." and that seemed to work fine. However, I am not sure how to actually use the library / project in my code. Do I make a new user library and put the jar files into it? And if I do that, how does the Maven part of it work?

Thanks so much. I'm really struggling here.

Comment: What do you intend to do after getting access to the Java client?

Comment: @NikhilSahu I want to be able to access data of Spotify songs, etc. to use in a Java project. I am still a bit new to Java, so I have only used standard Java libraries, etc. I really just want to be able to pull data down like you can do in Python, which seems to allow you to do it much easier.

Comment: Is your question addressed with the below answer?

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve the issue using the information from the below answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any maven dependency, you simply add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/se.michaelthelin.spotify/spotify-web-api-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>se.michaelthelin.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotify-web-api-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your dependencies in your pom.xml. Maven will automatically import the jars into your `.m2` directory when you build, and you can use import them into our code the regular way

Comment: When you say add to your pom file, do you mean the pom file attached to the spotify-web-api-java project, or do I need to make my own Maven project or something of the sort that incorporates a pom file where I list that dependency? Thank you for the help. I am just very unclear on the process, and a lot of tutorial and the like seem to infer lots of prior knowledge.